# Drupal Domain Access vs Multi-Site in Civi

Tags: drupal, multisite

What is the best way to implement CiviCRM for multiple sites?
I'm a little familiar with Domain Access and less with Multi-Site in Civi.

I'd like to have two front-end sites share one CiviCRM database, with a user from site A having access to the complete database and a user from site B having only access to site B contacts and contributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi-Site is the way to go http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation

With Domain Access you can get into trouble because CiviCRM would expect one domain per "civicrm.settings.php".

Comment: Just a note that you can use Domain Access, but you must handle setting the `CIVICRM_DOMAIN_ID` in `civicrm.settings.php` via a `switch` statement (or, if your Domain Access IDs and CiviCRM Domain IDs match, set the latter from the former).  The multi-site documentation covers this scenario.